# Particles emitter and dynamics

Tags: particles

[image]

Dear Folks.

Im trying to do some dynamics which is coarse particles entering into the grinding table and then crushed by the three rollers and fine particles extracted upwards at the outlet by help of fan.

Is it possible to accomplish this by a single particle or we need add one or more particles with different geometry and wind dynamics.

As im stick to the basic of Lightwave 3d particles.
I cannot add different groups for wind or curve unaffected by other.(Blender)

Even in add in separate collection a wind dynamics affecting all particles.

Please kindly resolve and give me a solution to achieve this in blender if possible..

please Download the concept blender file attached in the link:
https://we.tl/t-jnYuTkLN52

Thanks

Comment: To start to think about some fake, it depends how final result should look like ... what all will be seen by viewer ... if crushed pieces ends like a dust (smoke) sucked by ventilator or still visible particles ... if you are looking for photo-realistic render or some schematic (principle) look. BTW your shared file expired ... to share file properly here (to be permanent) use https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Agreed with above... bearing in mind: 'the final product is pixels',  I think it's important, here, to give us some indication of what you'd like the viewer to **see**, in the end. (Shots, style).

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=B0QwwX10" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/B0QwwX10/)

Comment: Sorry Dear Vklidu, I uploaded the file now. Kind check this file, there roller and grinding table will be rotating. Yes crushed pieces end like a dust or separate pixels with some generated while grinding. And all will be extracted or suction by a fan. well some of the particles which is coarse will hit above the fins of separator and drop down gets grind and extracted..

Comment: HI Robin Betts!  I will show the viewers in a single shot with a top camera view little tilted to some degree. so viewers can see the 1. grinding table rotating, 2. particles grinding on a roller,   3.fine products or dust  extracted upwards.  Shot duration: 15 seconds  including opening and closing the enclosure. Thanks

Comment: it will be helpful if some manipulated smoke that will be generated by grinding.

Comment: And one of the big issue is here is The model is  detailed one so I cannot handle it for showing the grinding operation so I will complete the dynamics with dummy objects say: only the outer shape with simple geometry and save the file and import. I tried for the first time baking but it failed to save and import. Any error ir mistake that im making? Blender version above 3.5.0

Answer (score 0):

To affect specific particle system just by specific group of forces stored in a Collection ... go to *Particle System Properties* > **Field Weights** and set desired collection with *Wind* force object.

For your other questions it sounds like some illusion of final would be better way than try to simulate something with Rigid Body.

---

*To start to think about some fake, it depends how final result should look like ... what all will be seen by viewer ... if crushed pieces ends like a dust (smoke) sucked by ventilator or still visible particles ... if you are looking for photo-realistic render or some schematic (principle) look.*

BTW your shared file expired ... to share file properly here (to be permanent) use https://blend-exchange.com